# Are there analogs to “Abba” & “Ima” for in-laws?

Tags: hebrew, names, aramaic, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

I know that “אבא” and “אמא” are originally Aramaic translations of the Hebrew “אבי” and “אמי” which have become adapted to Hebrew, especially in the accusative case.  Are there similar forms in Aramaic corresponding to “חמי” (or is that “חותני”?) or “חמותי”?

Comment: חותני is son-in-law. Father-in-law is חמי

Comment: For those that are confused, Vram is mentioning the same word that is used today for "groom" :)

Comment: _Chosen_ is a father-in-law. _Chasan_ is a son-in-law (and a bridegroom). Two different words. (And, yes, _cham_ is also a father-in-law.)

Comment: @J.C.Salomon, I think Aramaic _aba_ and _ima_ are "father" and "mother"; OTOH Hebrew _avi_ and _imi_ are "my father" and "my mother".

Comment: @msh210, see http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/u/up0104.htm#555 for an example where Onkelus translates Hebrew _avi_ to Aramaic _aba_.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon, very well. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

The problem becomes resolved when (iy"H) you have children. Then your in-laws become grandparents and you can call them as appropriate in their new role.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of. What to call your in-laws is always awkward, and I think the same is true in the Jewish community.

Rabbi Hershel Schachter notes that when he got married, it would be disrespectful to call his mother-in-law by her first name; he tried "Mrs. Stein" (or whatever her name was) but she said that was too formal; they settled on "Mom", I think.

Comment: I understand an old (now unused AFAIK) way of referring to one's parents-in-law in English is as "Father [surname]" and "Mother [surname]".

Answer (score 2):

One could use the Yiddish words - Shver or Shvigger.

Comment: I thought so; they have other ideas. ☹